# Not able to aggregate in case statement in hive query

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, case

I have data like below:

```
SELECT 
    mtrans.merch_num,
    mtrans.card_num 
FROM a_sbp_db.merch_trans_daily mtrans 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.product_holding ph ON mtrans.card_num = ph.acc_num 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.cust_demo cdemo ON cdemo.cust_id = ph.cust_id
WHERE mtrans.transaction_date LIKE '2017-09%' AND person_org_code='P' AND ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 30;



+-----------+----------------------------+
| merch_num | card_num                   |
+-----------+----------------------------+
|         1 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXURMX |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXIE6X |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDA8X |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7D1X |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTJ2X |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQQWX |
|         2 | 4659XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXY4EX |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRDOX |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0O3X |
|         2 | 4658XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNVBX |
+-----------+----------------------------+
```

I want to aggregate trans_amt by merch_num only if I get unique card_num more than 1.

In simple Query I can do it:

```
SELECT 
    mtrans.merch_num,
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'MMM-yyyy') AS process_month,
SUM(mtrans.trans_amt) AS total_age_less_30_1 
FROM a_sbp_db.merch_trans_daily mtrans 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.product_holding ph ON mtrans.card_num = ph.acc_num 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.cust_demo cdemo ON cdemo.cust_id = ph.cust_id
WHERE mtrans.transaction_date LIKE '2017-09%' AND person_org_code='P' AND  ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 30 
GROUP BY 
    mtrans.merch_num having count(distinct mtrans.card_num) > 1;

+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
| merch_num | process_month | total_age_less_30_1 |
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
|         2 | Nov-2017      | 2147.5              |
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Here I am able to skip merchant - 5493036 as it doesn't have unique cards more than 1.

But I have multiple conditions in where & want to write 1 query only.
Using case statement I am able to do it like below:

```
SELECT mtrans.merch_num,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'MMM-yyyy') AS process_month,
    NVL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 30)
            THEN mtrans.trans_amt ELSE 0 END), NULL)
            AS total_age_less_30_1,
    NVL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) >= 30
                    AND ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 40)
            THEN mtrans.trans_amt ELSE 0 END), NULL)
            AS total_age_30_40_1
FROM a_sbp_db.merch_trans_daily mtrans
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.product_holding ph ON mtrans.card_num = ph.acc_num
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.cust_demo cdemo ON cdemo.cust_id = ph.cust_id   
WHERE mtrans.transaction_date LIKE '2017-09%'
    AND person_org_code='P'
GROUP BY
    mtrans.merch_num

+-----------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| merch_num | process_month | total_age_less_30_1 | total_age_30_40_1 |
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|       3   | Nov-2017      | 0                   | 0                 |
|       4   | Nov-2017      | 0                   | 0                 |
|       1   | Nov-2017      | 2.49                | 203.68            |
|       2   | Nov-2017      | 2147.5              | 4907              |
|       5   | Nov-2017      | 0                   | 0                 |
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

I want to make 2.49 as NULL as for that merchant, more than 1 unique card is not present.

I am not able to apply having condition to check if unique card no is more than 1 then only I have to show the sum(trans_amt)

when I apply and condition in case statement, I get below error:

```
SELECT 
    mtrans.merch_num,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'MMM-yyyy') AS process_month,
    NVL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 30 and count(distinct mtrans.card_num) > 1) 
            THEN mtrans.trans_amt ELSE 0 END), NULL)
            AS total_age_less_30_1,
    NVL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) >= 30
                    AND     ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 40 and count(distinct mtrans.card_num) > 1)
            THEN mtrans.trans_amt ELSE 0 END), NULL)
            AS total_age_30_40_1                
FROM a_sbp_db.merch_trans_daily mtrans 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.product_holding ph ON mtrans.card_num = ph.acc_num 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.cust_demo cdemo ON cdemo.cust_id = ph.cust_id
WHERE mtrans.transaction_date LIKE '2017-09%' 
    AND person_org_code='P' 
GROUP BY 
    mtrans.merch_num;


ERROR: AnalysisException: aggregate function must not contain aggregate parameters: sum(CASE WHEN (round(datediff(mtrans.transaction_date, cdemo.date_birth) / 365) < 30 AND count(DISTINCT mtrans.card_num) > 1) THEN mtrans.trans_amt ELSE 0 END)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You can't use `count(distinct..` or any other aggregate function inside `SUM`. use it external to  arguments  of `SUM` and form your condition.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be because you have count inside the SUM statement. This is what you must try, Let me know how it goes :

```
SELECT 
    mtrans.merch_num,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'MMM-yyyy') AS process_month,
    NVL(CASE
        WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 30 and count(distinct mtrans.card_num) > 1) 
            THEN SUM(mtrans.trans_amt) ELSE 0 END, NULL)
            AS total_age_less_30_1,
    NVL(CASE
        WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) >= 30
                    AND     ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date,cdemo.date_birth)/365) < 40 and count(distinct mtrans.card_num) > 1)
            THEN SUM(mtrans.trans_amt) ELSE 0 END, NULL)
            AS total_age_30_40_1                
FROM a_sbp_db.merch_trans_daily mtrans 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.product_holding ph ON mtrans.card_num = ph.acc_num 
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.cust_demo cdemo ON cdemo.cust_id = ph.cust_id
WHERE mtrans.transaction_date LIKE '2017-09%' 
    AND person_org_code='P' 
GROUP BY 
    mtrans.merch_num;
```

Comment: Still facing similar error:    ERROR: AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): nvl(CASE WHEN (round(datediff(mtrans.transaction_date, cdemo.date_birth) / 365) < 30 AND count(DISTINCT mtrans.card_num) > 1) THEN sum(mtrans.trans_amt) ELSE 0 END, NULL)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it in a better way as follows.

> (PS: I didn't have any hive access, so I am doing this using Postgresql using regular SQL. So, it should be easier to adapt to Hive SQL).

Here is my SQL Table and records inserted in the table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hivetest (
   merchant_id INTEGER,
   card_number TEXT,
   customer_dob TIMESTAMP,
   transaction_dt TIMESTAMP,
   transaction_amt DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO hivetest VALUES
(1, 'A', '1997-12-01', '2017-11-01', 10.0),
(2, 'A', '1997-12-01', '2017-11-01', 11.0),
(2, 'B', '1980-12-01', '2017-11-01', 12.0),
(3, 'A', '1997-12-01', '2017-11-01', 13.0),
(3, 'A', '1997-12-01', '2017-11-01', 14.0),
(4, 'A', '1997-12-01', '2017-11-01', 15.0),
(4, 'C', '1980-12-01', '2017-11-01', 16.0);
```

First, you need to join the tables and generate a dataset that gives you the `transaction_age (transaction_dt - customer_dob`). I have most of the data for date subtraction in this single table, but simple INNER JOIN(s) should suffice to achieve this. Anyways, here is the query for the same.

```
SELECT
    merchant_id, card_number, DATE(customer_dob) customer_dob, DATE(transaction_dt) transaction_dt,
    DATE_PART('year', DATE(transaction_dt)) - DATE_PART('year', DATE(customer_dob)) transaction_age,
    transaction_amt
FROM hivetest ORDER BY 1;
```

This results in the data as follows.

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| merchant_id | card_number | customer_dob | transaction_dt | transaction_age |transaction_amt |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|           1 |      A      | 1997-12-01   | 2017-11-01     |              20 |           10.0 |
|           2 |      A      | 1997-12-01   | 2017-11-01     |              20 |           11.0 |
|           2 |      B      | 1980-12-01   | 2017-11-01     |              37 |           12.0 |
|           3 |      A      | 1997-12-01   | 2017-11-01     |              20 |           13.0 |
|           3 |      A      | 1997-12-01   | 2017-11-01     |              20 |           14.0 |
|           4 |      A      | 1997-12-01   | 2017-11-01     |              20 |           15.0 |
|           4 |      C      | 1980-12-01   | 2017-11-01     |              37 |           16.0 |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

The above dataset will allow you to categorise the SUM of transaction amounts based on the `transaction_age` as you want. The trick is to have the above query in a sub-query and use the results of this subquery to categorize. Here is the query to do the same.

```
SELECT
    merchant_id,
    -- Transaction Age less than 30
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_age <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_30,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_age <= 30 THEN transaction_amt ELSE 0 END) sum_30,

    -- Transaction Age between 30 and 40
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_age > 30 AND transaction_age <= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) case_30_40,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_age > 30 AND transaction_age <= 40 THEN transaction_amt ELSE 0 END) sum_30_40
FROM
(
    SELECT
        merchant_id, transaction_amt,
        DATE_PART('year', DATE(transaction_dt)) - DATE_PART('year', DATE(customer_dob)) transaction_age
    FROM hivetest
) m
GROUP BY merchant_id ORDER BY 1;
```

This results in the categorised output as below which gives you the count of transactions and sum of transaction amounts for each category for each merchant:

```
+-------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------+
| merchant_id | count_30 | sum_30 | case_30_40 | sum_30_40 |
+-------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------+
|           1 |        1 |   10.0 |          0 |         0 |
|           2 |        1 |   11.0 |          1 |      12.0 |
|           3 |        2 |   27.0 |          0 |         0 |
|           4 |        1 |   15.0 |          1 |      16.0 |
+-------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Now, this is our dataset which is more or less the final result. However, as per your requirement, you are only interested in merchants which have more than 1 unique cards (`COUNT(DISTINCT card_number) > 1`).

So, lets write another query which gives us this. Below is the query which calculates this and based on the criteria, it marks the flag as TRUE or FALSE indicating whether or not we are interested in that merchant or not.

```
SELECT
    merchant_id,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT card_number) > 1 THEN
            TRUE
        ELSE
            FALSE
    END has_distinct_cards_gt_1
FROM hivetest GROUP BY merchant_id ORDER BY 1
```

This gives the output as below.

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| merchant_id | has_distinct_cards_gt_1 |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           1 |                   false |
|           2 |                   true  |
|           3 |                   false |
|           4 |                   true  |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Now, we are almost done. We just need to join these two tables and then based on the `has_distinct_cards_gt_1`, display the columns accordingly from the dataset generated previously.

Here is the final join query and resultset data generated.

```
SELECT
    merchants_all.merchant_id,

    -- Age < 30
    CASE
        WHEN merchants_cards.has_distinct_cards_gt_1 THEN
            sum_30
        ELSE
            0
    END total_sum_30,

    -- Age in 30 and 40
    CASE
        WHEN merchants_cards.has_distinct_cards_gt_1 THEN
            sum_30_40
        ELSE
            0
    END total_sum_30_40
FROM
  (
      SELECT
            merchant_id,
            SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_age <= 30 THEN transaction_amt ELSE 0 END) sum_30,
            SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_age > 30 AND transaction_age <= 40 THEN transaction_amt ELSE 0 END) sum_30_40
      FROM
      ( 
            SELECT merchant_id, DATE_PART('year', DATE(transaction_dt)) - DATE_PART('year', DATE(customer_dob)) transaction_age, transaction_amt
            FROM hivetest
      ) m
      GROUP BY merchant_id
  ) merchants_all
JOIN
  (
     SELECT merchant_id, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT card_number) > 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END has_distinct_cards_gt_1
     FROM hivetest GROUP BY merchant_id ORDER BY 1
  ) merchants_cards
ON
(merchants_all.merchant_id = merchants_cards.merchant_id);
```

And this generates your final data, which you need.

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| merchant_id | total_sum_30 | total_sum_30_40 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|           1 |            0 |               0 |
|           2 |         11.0 |            12.0 |
|           3 |            0 |               0 |
|           4 |         15.0 |            16.0 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Deepak,Thanks for the help but unique card numbers will also be different agewise, you below query gives global merchant level unique card. It also has to be age wise.   SELECT
    merchant_id,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT card_number) > 1 THEN
            TRUE
        ELSE
            FALSE
    END has_distinct_cards_gt_1
FROM hivetest GROUP BY merchant_id ORDER BY 1

Answer (score 0):

COUNT inside SUM is the problem.
Here is a solution. I haven't tested it though. 
It's not obvious which table person_org_code belongs to. If it is in merch_trans_daily, then add person_org_code = 'P' to the where clause in the view. Let's know whether it works!

```
WITH mtrans_count AS
(SELECT merch_num,
        COUNT(1) AS cnt
   FROM a_sbp_db.merch_trans_daily
  WHERE mtrans.transaction_date LIKE '2017-09%'  
)
SELECT mtrans.merch_num
    ,FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'MMM-yyyy') AS process_month
    ,NVL(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN (
                        ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date, cdemo.date_birth) / 365) < 30
                        AND mtrans_count.cnt > 1
                        )
                    THEN mtrans.trans_amt
                ELSE 0
                END), NULL) AS total_age_less_30_1
    ,NVL(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN (
                        ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date, cdemo.date_birth) / 365) >= 30
                        AND ROUND(DATEDIFF(mtrans.transaction_date, cdemo.date_birth) / 365) < 40
                        AND mtrans_count.cnt > 1
                        )
                    THEN mtrans.trans_amt
                ELSE 0
                END), NULL) AS total_age_30_40_1
FROM a_sbp_db.merch_trans_daily mtrans
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.product_holding ph ON mtrans.card_num = ph.acc_num
INNER JOIN a_sbp_db.cust_demo cdemo ON cdemo.cust_id = ph.cust_id
INNER JOIN mtrans_count  ON mtrans_count.merch_num = mtrans.merch_num
WHERE mtrans.transaction_date LIKE '2017-09%'
    AND person_org_code = 'P'
GROUP BY mtrans.merch_num;
```